# Apache Pig: Encountered "<EOF>" Error

Tags: syntax-error, apache-pig

My Pig Script is:

```
register /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/pig/lib/piggybank.jar

SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize 1024000;
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize 1024000;
SET pig.noSplitCombination true;

DEFINE format `format_text.py $EMOJI $ACRONYM` SHIP ('$STREAM_FILE_PATH/format_text.py');

input_data = LOAD '$DATA_INPUT';
result = STREAM input_data THROUGH format;

STORE result into '$DATA_OUTPUT';
```

When i run this, I get an error: `[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - java.io.IOException: org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 13.`

I do not see any problem with the syntax in the script. Can some one help me what the problem could be.

Comment: ";" missing in line 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy

there is `;` missing on line one

```
register /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
```